# Access Control Allow Origin In Squarespace Image?

Tags: javascript, squarespace

Cross Origin Domain Access problem in Squarespace Images.

Here's the error:

> Image from origin 'http://static1.squarespace.com' has been blocked
>   from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.davidjaubert.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

How can it be resolved ?

Comment: I am able to see the image on your site. CORS won't take an effect unless you try to load images via AJAX.